# Sort a dataframe in R using a list that is not numeric or alphabetic, but is ordered

Tags: r

I have a list of weeks of the year that are ordered by the academic calendar that I want to order a data frame by.

```
weeks <- c("Sept W1", "Sep W2", "Sep W3", "Sept W4",
        "Oct W1", "Oct W2", "Oct W3", "Oct W4",
        "Nov W1", "Nov W2", "Nov W3", "Nov W4")
```

My data currently looks like the following, and I want to plot it demonstrating change in my week sum over the year, beginning with September, not April.

```
> newDat %>% group_by(week) %>% summarise(sum_all = sum(week_sum))
Source: local data frame [48 x 2]

       week sum_all
      (chr)   (dbl)
1  April W1   46840
2  April W2   52729
3  April W3   51285
4  April W4   51241
5    Aug W1   12089
```

As you can see, I'm using dplyr, but maybe there's an easier way to do this with a base function? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you have made weeks a factor?  Then it would have an inherent proper ordering.

Comment: I agree with @Joe, make it an (ordered) factor.

Comment: I suppose that should've been an answer, not a question, but I thought perhaps it was more complicated than that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create `week` as an [ordered factor](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html), then the data will be sorted in the order you designate inherently.

```
weeks <- c("Sep W1", "Sep W2", "Sep W3", "Sep W4",
         "Oct W1", "Oct W2", "Oct W3", "Oct W4",
         "Nov W1", "Nov W2", "Nov W3", "Nov W4")

weekdata <- c("Nov W1" "Nov W1" "Sep W1" "Sep W2" "Oct W1" "Sep W3")

weekdata.f <- factor(weekdata,levels=weeks, ordered=TRUE)

weekdata.order = sort(weekdata.f)

weekdata.order
```